# Value Error: Too Many Values to Unpack in an object forloop

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am getting the error below when trying to set a list of objects. This wasn't happening earlier with my data but now it is.

Is there a better method to writing the `obj_list_dictize` method to handle these kinds of problems?

Thanks!

```
Module ckan.lib.dictization:79 in obj_list_dictize
>>  obj, capacity = obj
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

---

```
def obj_list_dictize(obj_list, context, sort_key=lambda x:x):
    '''Get a list of model object and represent it as a list of dicts'''

    result_list = []
    active = context.get('active', True)

    for obj in obj_list:
        if context.get('with_capacity'):
            obj, capacity = obj
            dictized = table_dictize(obj, context, capacity=capacity)
        else:
            dictized = table_dictize(obj, context)
        if active and obj.state != 'active':
            continue
        result_list.append(dictized)

    return sorted(result_list, key=sort_key)
```

Comment: can you provide what `obj_list` looks like ?

Comment: `obj, capacity = obj` in this line obj has more than two items.

Comment: @MooingRawr it looks like this `[(u'9d409101-8c4a-4c53-9e5d-3ee775dae55a', u’Turtles’, None, u'active'), (u'eeb7624e-76e4-443a-9c6b-b1f429a12955', u’Monkeys’, None, u'active'), (u'9e3d932f-4d53-406e-ad32-ee73e124ea1d', u'Transactions’, None, u'active'), (u'40d13612-ad43-4da5-b925-b33e662ef4bc', u'Web Logs', None, u'active')]`

Comment: What do you expect to "unpack" when each `obj` has 4 items in it, and you only specify 2 variables? did you want the first item to be the `obj` and the rest be in `capacity`?

Comment: @MooingRawr not really sure why its here, this is a open source platform

Comment: I am assuming we can remove the line `obj, capacity = obj` ince we arent passing anything to it anyway.

Comment: `dictized = table_dictize(obj, context, capacity=capacity)` hints at that they want a capacity to be set, but what is capacity suppose to hold? only you would know.

Comment: @mystycs What is the code *supposed* to do? Why does the data format changed?

Comment: It looks like it holds a True or False value yet the funciton isnt taking anything in, I think its poor coding.

Comment: I changed the line `obj, capacity = obj ` to           `obj, capacity = obj, context.get('with_capacity')` and it looks like its passing the correct value in that it was looking for before. Works now. I assume this is what they were trying to do.